# How to add/append string to blob in Google Apps Script (Google Drive API)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps

This code does work, except this part `Drive.Files.update(thefile, theFileID, updatedBlob);`

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B0RcUNcUERU5MGpIaEXXXXXXXX");
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("NcUERXXXXXXXXERU5UWQUTZKY2X2"); 
var file2 = DriveApp.getFileById("NcUERXXXXXXXXERU5UWDDDDDDD2"); 

var myString = "sometext";
var updatedBlob = file.getBlob() + myString;

var myFileName = "StringAddedFile.mp4";  
var thefile = {
  title: myFileName,
  mimeType: 'video/mp4'
};

var allFilesByName = folder.getFilesByName(myFileName);
while (allFilesByName.hasNext()) {
  var thisFile = allFilesByName.next();
  var theFileID = thisFile.getId();
  var myVar = Drive.Files.update(thefile, theFileID, updatedBlob);
};
```

I have tried:

```
file.getBlob() + myString;
file.getBlob().getDataAsString() + myString;
file.getBlob().getDataAsString() + file2.getBlob().getDataAsString();
file.getAs() + file2.getAs();
file.getBlob() + file2.getBlob();
```

...

Getting this error message: `"The mediaData parameter only supports Blob types for upload."`

How can I add/append `myString` to `file`?

Comment: In Apps script you should use DriveApp class to access drive files and folders. Here is the link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app

Comment: @KRR thank you, I do have access, I just don't know how to add myString to the blob file.

Comment: It is not about access, it is about the class you have to call in Apps Script. Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry, var myVar = Drive.Files.update(thefile, theFileID, file.getBlob()); does work.

But I want to add myString to file.getBlob() & then update the file - like this file.getBlob() + myString - but I'm getting an error.

Comment: Post the error please. You can also check the logs if that string is getting appended or not.

Comment: @KRR 
sorry, I was trying to change language, because I'was getting it on russian "The mediaData parameter only supports Blob types for upload." on this line   var myVar = Drive.Files.update(thefile, theFileID, (file.getBlob() + myString));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to add something to a `mimeType: 'video/mp4'` file.  It looks like you need to create a blob from the string.  You can use the Utilities service to do that.

### For String

- Create a base 64 encoded string
- encoded string as a byte array

### For file

- Get file as blob
- Convert blob to bytes

### Combine

- Combine bytes of both files
- Update file as blob with another blob

### The code:

```
var myString = "sometext";
var encoded = Utilities.base64Encode(myString);
var byteDataArray = Utilities.base64Decode(encoded);

var file = DriveApp.getFileById("File ID here");
var fileAsBlob = file.getBlob();
var fileAsBytes = fileAsBlob.getBytes();

var combinedBytes = byteDataArray.concat(fileAsBytes);
var allBytesAsBlob = Utilities.newBlob(combinedBytes);

var updatedBlob = Drive.Files.update(thefile, theFileID, allBytesAsBlob);
```

This is a suggestion to try.  Haven't tested it.  Don't know if it will work, but no-one else has answered, so can't hurt to try.  I'll leave it up to you to try, and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Thank you mate, I tried the code  - it does work, but it overrides the whole file. I get my "thefile" with content "sometext". Maybe, there is a way that I can append "sometext" to my existing "video/mp4" file?
Again. thank you for your help.

Comment: var myString = file.getBlob().getDataAsString() + "sometext"
var encoded = Utilities.base64Encode(myString);
var byteDataArray = Utilities.base64Decode(encoded); 
var stringAsBlob = Utilities.newBlob(byteDataArray);

var updatedBlob = Drive.Files.update(thefile, theFileID, stringAsBlob);

does work :) thank you again :) looks like I just get some encoding problem, cuz video is not playable anymore. But I know how to add to the Blob - so thank you very much.

Comment: I posted a new idea.  But I guess you figured it out.  Yah, I would think that bytes from a string would break the mp4 file.

Comment: Got this message "The mediaData parameter only supports Blob types for upload." on this line var updatedBlob = Drive.Files.update(thefile, theFileID, combinedBytes);  :)

Comment: Yah, I'm not sure how to combine the bytes, I just guessed that it's an array that could be combined. Actually, I should have used a different method. Used concat instead.  See update in answer.

Comment: I'm getting the same message, because Drive.Files.update only supports Blob type as a 3-rd parameter. I need to change "combinedBytes" to Blob type somehow :)

Comment: Oh!  Of course!.  yah.  See new line `Utilities.newBlob(bytes)`

Comment: Getting new message - "JSON: Not Found" on this line var updatedBlob = Drive.Files.update(thefile, theFileID, allBytesAsBlob);  Sorry, mate :)

Comment: It's all good, thank you very much for everything.  I'll play with encodings by your first advice with "stringAsBlob" & I think I'm gonna figure it out :)

Comment: :)))) sorry, mate, your last code does work - I got this error "JSON: Not Found", because "theFileID" didn't have any value in this line "var updatedBlob = Drive.Files.update(thefile, theFileID, allBytesAsBlob);"
Thank you very much for your help ^^